# Possible to remove off-screen dom elements from (extremely) large list to save CPU?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a page that, in short, has a very long list of items (~3000) on it. Each of these items needs to be able to listen for JS events. Currently, rendering them all on screen produces visible stutter and input delay, and chrome reports that the tab is using 100% cpu.

I've narrowed the problem down to this, and I know that there are solutions for this on native platforms such as android and ios that only render the items on the list +a buffer zone for above and below. I was wondering if there was a known implementation of this that exists for the web, or if I'm simply wasting my time planning on hacking something together.

Comment: I have zero affiliation with this product, but have you looked at something like this? https://infinite-scroll.com/

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I'll look into it.